# How to use a function that returns a table within an INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a function that returns 5 columns (address) as a table. I need to use the result to insert into another table:

```
    INSERT INTO mytable
        (col1, address1, address2, address3, address4, address5)
    SELECT 
        Id, HouseNo, Street, PostCode, City, Country
    FROM @someTableType
    JOIN dbo.GetAddress(@customerId);
```

The `Id` column is from `@someTableType`. The rest of the columns are returned by the function.

But the above doesn't work.

What is the correct way?

Comment: a `JOIN` without an `ON` is an error (except `CROSS JOIN`). *is* there some logic to match the rows between those in `@someTableType` and those returned by `GetAddress`?

Comment: Please expand on 'doesn't work'. Maybe you want `cross apply, not `join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your query to this

```
INSERT INTO mytable
        (col1, address1, address2, address3, address4, address5)
    SELECT 
        someTableType.Id, adress.HouseNo, adress.Street, adress.PostCode, adress.City, 
    adress.Country
    FROM @someTableType
    Cross Apply dbo.GetAddress(@customerId) as adress;
```

but you have change function beacause it always return same resault because of @customerId always have one value